# Use sed to delete line, and the one below if it contains 1 pattern, but not another

Tags: bash, sed, bsd

Found a couple of examples similar to what I want but they don't work for me, or others judging by the comments.

I want this

```
#Hello my name is Chris
next line of random txt
#Hello my name is Bob
next line of random txt
Hello Ana is my name #
next line of random txt
Another Line
```

to be this

```
#Hello my name is Chris
next line of random txt
Hello Ana is my name #
next line of random txt
Another Line
```

Lines that contain "#" but not "Chris" or "Ana" get deleted along with the line below them.

Comment: sed is for `s/old/new`, **that is all**. For anything else you should be using awk. All currently posted sed solutions, including the accepted answer, will fail if the `#Hello my name is Bob` is immediately followed by an identical line.If that's an issue then update your question to include that situation in the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given input:

```
#Hello my name is Chris
next line of random txt 1
#Hello my name is Bob
next line of random txt 2
Hello Ana is my name #
next line of random txt 3
Another Line
```

Either the script:

```
sed -e '/#/ { /Chris/b' -e '/Ana/b' -e 'N; d; }' data
```

or the script:

```
sed -E \
    -e '/#/ {
                 /(Chris|Ana)/b
                 N
                 d
            }' \
    data
```

generates:

```
#Hello my name is Chris
next line of random txt 1
Hello Ana is my name #
next line of random txt 3
Another Line
```

This seems to match your specification.  The first doesn't even use extended regular expression (ERE) syntax, so it is maximally portable, but the second shows that it could easily be modified to use ERE syntax.  With BSD `sed`, you can't have a semicolon after the branch (`b`) command; what would follow has to go on another line or in another `-e` argument.  The `b` without an explicit label means 'branch to end of script'.

Comment: Awesome again perfect. Thanks for your help! Used the first example

Comment: You can also tweak #1 to `sed '/#/ { /\(Chris\|Ana\)/b; N; d; }' data` (to enjoy the picket-fence effect)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/Chris\|Ana/b;/#/!b;$!N;d' file
```

If a line contains either `Chris` or `Ana` break,i.e. do no further processing and print as normal. Likewise if a line does not contain `#`. If the current line is not the last, get the next and delete both. Otherwise if it is the last line delete it too.